# static variables initialization order between many classes

Tags: c++, static-methods, static-members

```
c.h   
class C{  
    static string s;  
}

c.cpp  
string C::s=D::staticMethod();

d.h  
class D{  
static string s;  
static string staticMethod();  
}

d.cpp  
string D::s("some string");  
string D::staticMethod(){  
    return s;  (***)  
}
```

this won't work, it stops at (***) because D::s has not been initialized.Is there any way to get d.cpp compiled before c.cpp?

Comment: It is a good thing that this doesn't compile! See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14 and http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.15

Comment: @Asher: Sadly, it does compile, but has undefined runtime behaviour. Even worse, in practice there's a 50-50 chance that it will run successfully, making the bug even harder to trace.

Comment: The only way you can know the order is if the objects are in the same .cpp file. Otherwise it can vary between different builds.

Comment: @Mike: Oh, right. I read "it stops at (*)" as "the compiler stops at (*)". I know the runtime behavior is undefined, but I thought he found a compiler which caught it. I suppose that was too optimistic of me - do compilers at least warn about this kind of thing? It should be detectable ("is this cpp file using a static defined in another?").

Answer (score 2):

Best reference for this IMHO:

[What's the "static initialization order fiasco"?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14)

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. If you really need this sort of behaviour, look up the Singleton pattern. But also think carefully whether you need that sort of coupling in your application.